# Raspi Edge impulse ERR

Tags: camera

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ edge-impulse-linux
Edge Impulse Linux client v1.4.7
Stored token seems invalid, clearing cache...
getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN studio.edgeimpulse.com
? What is your user name or e-mail address (edgeimpulse.com)? xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
? What is your password? [hidden]

? To which project do you want to connect this device? Dhayananth / Food
[GST] checking for /etc/os-release
? Select a microphone (or run this command with --disable-microphone to skip sel
ection) bcm2835_headpho - bcm2835 Headphones
[SER] Using microphone hw:1,0
[SER] Using camera /base/soc/usb@7e980000/usb-port@1-1.2 starting...
[SER] Connected to camera
[WS ] Connecting to wss://remote-mgmt.edgeimpulse.com
camera error gstreamer process was killed with code (1)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Tell us what you are doing. What is the issue? What are you trying to do? What is your Raspberry Pi model? What is the OS you are using? See [Asking a good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.